# Rails Missing Template Error

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, view, haml, missing-template

I got the following error when trying to run my Rails server:

```
 ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template pages/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem (which has happened to me on 2 occasions so I thought I would share the answer for reference) is that I forgot to add the haml gem. Silly problem that cost me way more time than it should have.